# Store and display data from mysql using laravel and vue js

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

So I have 2 project files, 1 for the homepage where users can submit data such as text and images, and the other one is for the admin pages, to read the submitted data from users, both project uses the same database.

The datas have been successfully stored and displayed in both projects, the problem is for the images, It's only showing the image path, not the image itself like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCxdi.png)

I tried to copy the image from the homepage to the adminpage but still it's just showing the image path only.

What could be the problem ? because In the homepage, If the user submit an image, The image will be uploaded to images/imgupload folder, and the data that will be sent to the database is like this :
images/imgupload/4cad6hMcc36c1dtGw6K1OUkRnAFCucEpDP44vN9B.jpg

Is it the right way to store image to a database? because then in the admin page, It will be only showing the path, not the image itself.

This is the methods in the homepage

```
methods: {
      async submitForm() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('text', this.form.text);
        formData.append('file', this.form.file);
  
        try {
          const response = await axios.post('/api/endpoint', formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
          });
  
          console.log(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      },
      uploadFile() {
        this.form.file = this.$refs.fileInput.files[0];
      },
    },
```

The controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'text' => 'required',
            'file' => 'required|file',
        ]);

        $formData = new FormData();
        $formData->text = $request->text;
        $formData->file = $request->file('file')->store('formdatas');
        $formData->save();

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Form data was saved successfully.']);
    }
```

The routes :

```
Route::post('/endpoint', function (Request $request) {
    $text = $request->input('text');
    $file = $request->file('file');
  
    $data = new FormData();
    $data->text = $text;
    $data->file = $file->store('images/imgupload');
    $data->save();
    
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Success']);
  });
```

Comment: How you read the images from the database? And where the images stored in the file system?

Comment: @GhanuBha

@GhanuBha thats the problem, the images stored in only the homepage project, while in the database, it's only storing the image path

this is how I read from the database

`public function index()
    {
        $formdatas = FormData::all();
        return Inertia::render('Formdatas/Index', ['formdatas' => $formdatas]);
    }
`

Comment: You mean file not move to the folder of the server?

Comment: @GhanuBha The uploaded files is stored in the storage/images/imgupload on the homepage project, but its not stored on the admin page, but I have tried to copy the image to the admin project, still it's only showing the path not the image itself

Comment: You don't need to store same file twice. You just need to access it in your admin area. Have you used <img> tag in your admin?

Comment: @GhanuBha I tried, but it's giving me error code 404

Comment: Then URL is the issue. Can you lease share both URLs where it works and where it return 404 error.

Comment: @GhanuBha
Im uploading the image like this
`$data->file = $file->store('public/images/imgupload', 'public');`

and im trying to display it like this
`<img :src="'http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/public/images/imgupload/' + formdatas.file" alt="">`

where is the problem can you help me ?

Comment: In browser in the inspect element which URL is create in admin where it not work and which URL in where it works. Match the  both URLs and also share with me.

Comment: @GhanuBha 
im trying to display the image with this url :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/public/uploaded/8qUipLNrpKwWVPpkk4CKDmBTQpHWvHMBk4Lx7vzM.png

where it says not found (404)

But the path is already correct

or perhaps you could help me change where I should upload the images and display it ?

Comment: Have you followed this?
`https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk`

Comment: @GhanuBha yes I have created the links

Comment: Then you have to use `/public/uploaded/IMAGE_FILE` OR `/uploaded/IMAGE_FILE`. Storage/app will be removed.